# Do we really want tools for our work?

Tags: team-management, time-management

I am running a small team and I am performing perfectly in my work.

But a few days ago one of my friends told me that we should try a tool or software package that will help increase productivity and and employee management too. with the help of the tool we can track the every employee status on the particular project and their overall performance. But I am not in mood to investing the tool at this moment.

So tell me,  I am already happy with my work performance without using any tool. so, should I buy a tool or can work continuously with my ongoing situation.

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. Have you asked the rest of the team whether they think they can benefit from new software? Are the team regularly meeting up to evaluate their performance and decide what improvements they can make? Assuming they do, that seems like a good opportunity to discuss the possible benefits of team collaboration software for example.

Comment: So you suggest me that team collaboration software is important. right?

Comment: I've voted to close since this is very much opinion-based, and recommendations would require knowing your team and your working style. Apparently you also don't realize that you're using tools - computer, e-mail, a word processor, spreadsheet, etc. Most of these improve your work performance a bit (well, my wife claims her computer decreases her performance...). Choosing additional tools should be guided by well-informed considerations about their effect on work performance and quality. If you're already performing optimally you don't need more tools. I'm not convinced that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for genuine feedback.

Comment: Lots of teams do find collaboration software useful. Your team can decide what's important in your environment.

Comment: Sure, I am going to organize the team meeting if they want a new software or tools then I'll provide them what they want. I don't want my productivity down.

Comment: I would advise not to consider a tool based on want. It is based on need with predicted measurable benefits. Make this analysis as objective as possible. Also, be prepared for a dip in productivity. New tools typically cause lower performance in the short run with improvements down the road. Plan on it.

Comment: Thank you David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advancement in tools increases work performance. It's been proven in our world since the industrial age and into our current technological age. There is no credible dispute to that general statement.

However, to answer this question for your specific project at this specific time, producing whatever it is you're producing, then that depends on the tools you are currently using and the proposed tools you are considering. Introducing new tools comes with inherent benefits, costs, and risks. You need to evaluate each alternative tool against those three criteria and choose the alternative that scores higher in benefits than costs and risks.

Your happiness and your perception of your work performance are immaterial to this analysis. What is material, notwithstanding the three criteria above, is your delivery performance of scope quality against your planned schedule and costs. These are objective values. If you are performing as promised based on your performance measurement baseline, then maybe doing nothing is your best alternative. If you are not, then evaluating different tools might be worth your time.

Comment: Sure David, I'll definitely focus on your valuable feedback and make it useful for my team and me also. 

cheers!!!